# `Drupal\DrupalExtension` extension file or class could not be located

Tags: 8, testing

I got this error upon launching behat tests:

> [Behat\Testwork\ServiceContainer\Exception\ExtensionInitializationException]
>   `Drupal\DrupalExtension` extension file or class could not be located.

Does any additional module is required?
Found https://www.drupal.org/project/behat but for d7

Comment: Did you require the extension via composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Drupal Extension requires no modules, only composer installation.

Execute:

`composer require drupal/drupal-extension='~3.0'`

See the docs for other setup information: https://github.com/jhedstrom/drupalextension/blob/master/README.md

**Update**

to install the latest version just use

```
composer require drupal/drupal-extension
```

[version 3 is kind of outdated and in this time latest version is 4.1]